# something like hit counter in MOSS

Tags: moss

i am hoping you can tell me how to get view logs counter of users. In other words, is there a way I could get a report of how many persons have viewed any document or upload any document or even logged.

Answer (score 1):

> When you install MOSS 2007 using the default install locations the MOSS 2007 log files will not reside in the “Program Files\Microsoft Office Servers\12.0\Logs” directory folder as expected. They will reside in the WSS directory folder “Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\web server extensions\12\Logs”.

From [MOSS Log Files](http://myitforum.com/cs2/blogs/dhite/archive/2007/04/08/moss-log-files.aspx)

Also take a look here: [Usage Event Logging in Windows SharePoint Services 3.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb814929.aspx) and this samples:

- [Usage Analysis Processing logs](http://blogs.msdn.com/leonidly/archive/2007/10/30/usage-analysis-processing-logs.aspx)
- [MOSS Usage Log Processing File parsing](http://vspug.com/wpowell/2007/06/22/moss-usage-log-processing-file-processing/)